# Espresso - checking recyclerview position for specific image

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-espresso

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to test whether or not a certain image is being show on a position in a recyclerview using espresso. I have a list of people, and when one of them is selected, I'm showing a selected indicator around his image in the recyclerview. So I want to check that, for instance, position 0 has this indicator showing. What I'm trying is this:

```
fun test(position: Int, @DrawableRes res: Int): ViewInteraction {
    return onView(withId(recyclerViewId)).check(matches(hasItemAtPosition(position, hasBackground(res))))
}

 private fun hasItemAtPosition(position: Int, matcher: Matcher<View>): Matcher<View> {
    return object : BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView::class.java) {

        override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
            description?.appendText("has item at position $position : ")
            matcher.describeTo(description)
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(recyclerView: RecyclerView): Boolean {
            val viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
                ?: return false
            return matcher.matches(viewHolder.itemView)
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine if I do it with withText rather than withBackground and match the text of the item.

The error I get looks like this:

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'has item at position 0 : has background with drawable ID: 2131231310' doesn't match the selected view.
    Expected: has item at position 0 : has background with drawable ID: 2131231310
```

I'm kind of new to espresso and testing in general, so hoping someone has any suggestions.

UPDATE:

The test method is inside a custom class I have looking like this:

```
class RecyclerViewWait(@IdRes val recyclerViewId: Int) {

test()
hasItemAtPosition()
}
```

So those two methods are in there as well (the ones above)

I am calling them from another class, like this:

```
override fun doesPositionContainImageInList(position: Int, imageRes: Int): ViewInteraction {
    return RecyclerViewWait(R.id.recyclerViewTest).checkBackground(position, imageRes)
```

Which in return is called from my Robot class like this:

```
fun isImageShown(): Boolean {
    return viewFinder.doesPositionContainImageInList(
        0,
        R.drawable.ic_selected_avatar
    ).isDisplayed()
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution that worked, ended up being this:

```
fun checkBackground(position: Int, @DrawableRes imageRes: Int): ViewInteraction {
    return onView(withId(recyclerViewId))
        .check(matches(hasItemAtPosition(position, hasDescendant(withDrawable(imageRes)))))
}

private fun hasItemAtPosition(position: Int, matcher: Matcher<View>): Matcher<View> {
    return object : BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView::class.java) {

        override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
            description?.appendText("has item at position $position : ")
            matcher.describeTo(description)
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(recyclerView: RecyclerView): Boolean {
            val viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
                ?: return false
            return matcher.matches(viewHolder.itemView)
        }
    }
}

private fun withDrawable(@DrawableRes resourceId: Int): Matcher<View> {
    return DrawableMatcher(resourceId)
}

private class DrawableMatcher(private val expectedId: Int) : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

    @Suppress("ReturnCount")
    override fun matchesSafely(target: View): Boolean {
        if (target !is ImageView || target.visibility == View.GONE) {
            return false
        }
        if (expectedId < 0) {
            return target.drawable == null
        }
        val resources = target.context.resources
        val expectedDrawable: Drawable =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, expectedId, target.context.theme)
                ?: return false
        val bitmap = getBitmap(target.drawable)
        val otherBitmap = getBitmap(expectedDrawable)

        return bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap)
    }

    private fun getBitmap(drawable: Drawable): Bitmap {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            drawable.intrinsicWidth,
            drawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }

    override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
        description?.appendText("isMatchingDrawableResource")
    }
}
```

With this I just ask checkBackground with the position and the imageRes that I want to check if is there. And I'm also checking that it is visible further down. I tried with isDisplayed from Espresso further up in the code, but that didn't work somehow.

Comment: This appears to come straight from [here](https://medium.com/@dbottillo/android-ui-test-espresso-matcher-for-imageview-1a28c832626f) which is fine but doesn't work with vectors

Answer (score 1):

Your custom matcher is **only** matching `hasBackground` with `viewHolder.itemView`, which is the **root view** of an adapter item, meaning the matcher will fail if the background of the root view does not match.

If one of the child views contains the background, then maybe you should wrap the matcher with `hasDescendant`, which allow the matcher to match all child views in the item:

```
val hasDescendantWithBackground = hasDescendant(hasBackground(res))
onView(withId(recyclerViewId)).check(matches(
    hasItemAtPosition(position, hasDescendantWithBackground)))
```

Also, `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition` may not work properly in your matcher if the position is offscreen (view not laid out yet).

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work, still gives me an error when I do this. But I think you're getting close to something!

Comment: Yes exactly the same error. I don't know if I'm possibly asking to check for the image wrongly? I'll update the question real quick.

Comment: I edited my comment, hopefully you can make sense of that and see if I'm messing up somewhere

Comment: Not sure if this help, but according to https://github.com/android/android-test/blob/master/espresso/core/java/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/HasBackgroundMatcher.java#L70 it looks like the matcher is comparing `BitmapDrawable` only, I'm guessing maybe your drawable is not a `BitmapDrawable`, but I'm not familiar with drawable types :(

Comment: Hmm me neither. Thanks for helping out!